# Xcode6 ipa distribution issue

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Did anybody have a luck to make and install an ipa file with Xcode6?

I developed the Swift app

I have created successfully an ipa file, with right provision where my device is presented. 
But when I try to install it to device via iTunes - in hangs

Any ideas?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to http://devforums.apple.com

Comment: Same for me. Did an ipa and iTunes hangs during install...

Comment: @BryanChen devforums.apple.com  is silent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode is still in beta and this turned out to be a known issue (had the same) - https://devforums.apple.com/message/984530#984530

tl;dr run this this in the command line :

```
ditto -xk /path/to/file.ipa /tmp/my_extract_path
ditto -ck --norsrc /tmp/my_extract_path /path/to/new_file.ipa
rm -r /tmp/my_extract_path
```

A new IPA will be generated which should install properly.

Comment: file.ipa is Xcode generated ipa? And new_file.ipa is a fixed ipa?

Comment: yes, you can change those values to whatever suits you