# Distributing Swift iOS applications ad-hoc

Tags: ios, swift, provisioning-profile, adhoc, xcode6

I have two empty iOS single view apps compiled to IPA through Xcode 6 beta 2. One is Objective-C, second one is Swift. Both of them have exactly the same code signing settings.
When distributing ad hoc with test flight or hockey, Objective-C version installs without a problem. Swift one errors out with 'Unable to download the app the moment'.

I ran iPhone Configuration Utility logs on it and this is what I get :

```
Jun 24 17:36:27  installd[3555] <Notice>: 0x2c1000 handle_install_for_ls: Install of "/var/mobile/Media/Downloads/-6680582027007079892/1462391056366119034" requested by itunesstored
Jun 24 17:36:29  installd[3555] <Notice>: 0x2c1000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Installing app com.MyApp.sTest
Jun 24 17:36:29  installd[3555] <Error>: 0x2c1000 verify_signer_identity: MISValidateSignatureAndCopyInfo failed for /var/tmp/install_staging.HEsTZS/foo_extracted/Payload/sTest.app/sTest: 0xe8008017
Jun 24 17:36:29  installd[3555] <Error>: 0x2c1000 do_preflight_verification: Could not verify executable at /var/tmp/install_staging.HEsTZS/foo_extracted/Payload/sTest.app
Jun 24 17:36:29  itunesstored[94] <Error>: 0x1ef7000 MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices: failed with -1
Jun 24 17:36:29  itunesstored[94] <Warning>: ERROR: MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices returned nil
Jun 24 17:36:29  lsd[3554] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installation failed for app com.MyApp.sTest
Jun 24 17:36:29  itunesstored[94] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installPhaseFinishedForProgress: com.MyApp.sTest.Installing - <NSProgress: phase=Installing; state=Failed; fractionCompleted=0.000000> called, removing progress from cache
Jun 24 17:36:30  installd[3555] <Error>: 0x2c1000 install_application: Could not preflight application install
Jun 24 17:36:30  installd[3555] <Error>: 0x2c1000 handle_install_for_ls: API failed
Jun 24 17:36:31  lsd[3554] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installation ended for app com.MyApp.sTest
```

Anybody has an idea what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Oh man I have the same problem here, I'm worried that this may be Apple blocking it.

Comment: Are you able to deploy to the device using cable?

Comment: Yes, it works when I'm deploying to a single device straight through Xcode. Cannot get it through on Testflight or Hockey though.

Comment: oh, what a shame, but the iOS8 SDK is _Beta_, the Xcode6 is _Beta_, and the Swift language is currently a _concept_ only and is not ready for commercial development.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a solution. This seems to be a known issue (17283374) with Xcode 6 beta.

https://devforums.apple.com/message/984530#984530

Fix that worked for me is to unpack and re-pack the ipa, stripping the extended attributes that are causing problems:

```
ditto -xk /path/to/file.ipa /tmp/my_extract_path
ditto -ck --norsrc /tmp/my_extract_path /path/to/new_file.ipa
rm -r /tmp/my_extract_path
```

Answer (score 0):

Same issue, here is my topic [Xcode6 ipa distribution issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24263294/xcode6-ipa-distribution-issue)

Can't install Swift ipa to my device via iTunes or TestFlight

I found one workaround for this - I created *.app file and successfully installed it to my device via iTunes. Not sure that this works for TestFlight, but at least you can send *.app and mobile provision file to your client

Comment: hey igor, saw that you've been able to save your ipa. you never ran into this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24263294/xcode6-ipa-distribution-issue ?

Comment: @christopher.ryan.cruz  yes, below workaround works like a charm